# Name numpys keywords with savez while using arbitrary number of arguments

Tags: python, numpy

I want to save a arbitrary number of np.arrays with an defined name.
Here is my example, considering I have a name list of three and (of course) three arrays to save:

```
import numpy as np

l = [np.random.random_integers(5, size = (3., 2.)), np.random.random_integers(5, size = (3., 2.)), np.random.random_integers(5, size = (3., 2.))]
lN = ['a', 'b', 'c']

a = np.savez('test.npz', *[l for i in l])
b = np.load('test.npz')
print b.keys()
```

Output:

```
['arr_1', 'arr_0', 'arr_2']
```

So how do I map the namelist `lN` to my arrays, to be saved with the correct name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
np.savez('test.npz',**{name:value for name,value in zip(lN,l)})
```

If you want to specify the names, use the keyword type of parameter.  Here I am doing that by expanding (with `**`) a dictionary.  I'm also using the newer dictionary version of a list comprehension.