# How to save multiple numpy array in npz in for loop?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I am trying to extract frequencies of around 2000 audio samples in a for loop and save all of them in one npz file.

```
for audio_file in value:
    audio_file_path = os.path.join(dir_path, key, audio_file)

    #get frequency from audio signal from sampling rate as 16000
    ys, sr = lb.core.load(audio_file_path, sr = 16000)
    ys = np.array(ys, dtype = np.float)

    #key is file name and ys is array
    np.savez(key, ys)
```

Comment: ok, what is your problem with the above code? could give more detail?

Comment: You give `savez` the name of the archive.  Use the `keyword` arguments, or `**adictionary` to specify the names for the individual array files.  `savez` is not designed to work iteratively.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30850702/name-numpys-keywords-with-savez-while-using-arbitrary-number-of-arguments

Answer (score -1):

When using numpy savez, first you should give it the save path and a name for the file that will be created, then the array(s) you want to save, see below"

```
np.savez("path to dir/file_name", key, ys)
```

see [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savez_compressed.html)

tell me if there is another problem with your code?

Comment: With each loop the previous array stored is replaced by the new array. The arrays are not getting stacked but replaced.